# dxTab Dynamic Font-Size

Tags: javascript, devextreme

I have a dxTab that I am trying to figure out how to create dynamic font-size for.

```
<div data-bind="dxTabs: { dataSource: SurveyQuestions, selectedIndex: currentIndex }">
    <div data-options="dxTemplate: {name: 'item'}">
        <div data-bind="text: text " style="font-size: 20px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to put a variable in font size instead or to database to font-size?

Basically there can be up to 5 tabs but when there is 5 tabs you cant see all the text, so I shrink the text by `2px` for reach additional tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
<div data-bind="dxTabs: { dataSource: SurveyQuestions }">
    <div data-options="dxTemplate: { name: 'item'}">
        <div data-bind="text: text, 
           style: { fontSize: $parent.SurveyQuestions.length < 5 ? '16px' : '12px' }"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/pmbuw7t2/

But I'm not sure it's the best solution.
In fresh 14.2 release dxTabs supports scrolling https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S171952

Hope this can help you.